# Variance of $\hat{\beta _0}$ in case of pure homoskedasticity

Tags: regression, variance, inference

Stock and Watson express the variance of $\hat{\beta _0}$ like 
$\hat{\sigma }^2_\hat{\beta _0}=\frac{E({X_{i}}^{2})}{n\sigma _{X}^{2}}\sigma ^{2}$, but starting from variance of $\hat{\beta _1}=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n\sigma_{X}^{2}}$ i proved only that $\hat{\sigma }^2_\hat{\beta _0}=\frac{1}{n}\sigma^{2}(1+\frac{\bar{X}^2}{\sigma_{X}^{2}})$, that is the same that is showed [here](http://www.utstat.utoronto.ca/alisong/Teaching/0708/Sta302/formulae.pdf).

How can i prove that are similar forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us depart from the heteroskedastic result 
$$
\sigma^2_{\hat\beta_0}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{var(H_iu_i)}{[E(H_i^2)]^2}$$
which Stock & Watson specialize to homoskedasticity here. Here, 
$$
H_i=1-\left(\frac{\mu_X}{E(X_i^2)}\right)X_i.
$$
We may always write
$$
var(H_iu_i)=E(H_i^2u_i^2)-[E(H_iu_i)]^2
$$
Under the maintained assumption of correct specification, $E(u_i|X_i)=0$ and hence, by the law of iterated expecations, as $H_i$ only depends on $X_i$,
$$
E(H_iu_i)=E(H_iE(u_i|X_i))=0
$$
Hence,
$$
var(H_iu_i)=E(H_i^2u_i^2)
$$
Again by the LIE,
$$
E(H_i^2u_i^2)=E(H_i^2E(u_i^2|X_i))
$$
which reduces to
$$
E(H_i^2E(u_i^2|X_i))=\sigma^2_uE(H_i^2) 
$$
under homoskedasticity. So
$$
\sigma^2_{\hat\beta_0}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{\sigma^2_uE(H_i^2)}{[E(H_i^2)]^2}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{\sigma^2_u}{E(H_i^2)}
$$
Let us study 
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(H_i^2)
&=&1-2\frac{\mu_XE(X_i)}{E(X_i^2)}+\frac{\mu_X^2}{(E(X_i^2))^2}E(X_i^2)\\
&=&1-2\frac{\mu_X^2}{E(X_i^2)}+\frac{\mu_X^2}{(E(X_i^2))^2}E(X_i^2)\\
&=&1-2\frac{\mu_X^2}{E(X_i^2)}+\frac{\mu_X^2}{E(X_i^2)}\\
&=&\frac{E(X_i^2)-2\mu_X^2+\mu_X^2}{E(X_i^2)}\\
&=&\frac{E(X_i^2)-\mu_X^2}{E(X_i^2)}\\
&=&\frac{\sigma^2_X}{E(X_i^2)},
\end{eqnarray*}
which gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now i try to backtrack, starting from the end. But it doesn't answer my question: if i know that $\hat{\beta _0}=\bar{Y}-\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X}\Rightarrow Var(\hat{\beta _0})=Var(\bar{Y}-\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X})=Var(\bar{Y})-\bar{X}^2Var(\hat{\beta_1})-2\bar{X}Cov(\bar{Y},\hat{\beta _1})\Rightarrow Var(\bar{Y})-\bar{X}^2Var(\hat{\beta_1})=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}(1+\frac{\bar{X}^2}{\sigma_{X}^{2}})$ , how can i pass from $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}(1+\frac{\bar{X}^2}{\sigma_{X}^{2}})$ to $\frac{E(X_{i}^{2})}{n\sigma_{X}^{2}}\sigma^{2}$?

Comment: This derivation is not valid under the assumptions in S&W, who treat $X_i$ as random, too. (This is why quantities such as $E(X_i)$ show up.) So you cannot just pull $\bar X$ out of the variance and covariance operator.

Comment: Ok. So let's suppose we don't know the variance of $Var(\hat{\beta_0})$: how can we derivate $\frac{1}{n}\frac{Var(H_iu_i)}{[E(H_{i}^{2})]^2}$ from $Var(\hat{\beta_1})=\frac{1}{n}\frac{Var[(X_i-\bar{X})u_i]}{({{\sigma_{X}}^{2}})^2}$?

Comment: I suggest you ask this as a separate question. In any case, a derivation for the first will not directly proceed from the second expression.

Comment: Ok, i'm quite confused now. Unfortunately Stock and Watson don't explain how derivate it, not even at the appendix. They only say: "The distribution in big samples of $\hat\beta _0$ is $N(\hat\beta_0,\sigma_{\hat\beta_0}^2)$, where $\sigma_{\hat\beta_0}^2=\frac{1}{n}\frac{var(H_iu_i)}{[E(H_{i}^{2})]^2}$" (pag. 101 Key concept 4.4). I tried to find a proof but nothing. I don't think we have to take it as a matter of fact...

Comment: ...which is why I suggested you ask a new question that you want a derivation of this expression, as the current one was on how to go to the homoskedastic formula (see your title). You now additionally seem to want a derivation for the formula in the heteroskedastic case.

Comment: Yes, because i calculated it pull out $\bar{X}$ from the variance but, like you rightly said, is not possible with v.a. Ok, i'll do as you say. Thanks again.